# Aggregating results of different calculations

Tags: java

This is my first post here, so forgive me for any formatting errors.

So as you can see my program requests the gender, # of accidents and year of car to display a fictitious insurance quote.

Based on all that information I need to add the subtotal of the insurance cost to the end.

I have my code working up until the Total Cost comment (posted it all for reference). I am stuck there because the genders have different base amounts. I'm trying to figure out a way to only do one if statement if it matches the gender that was input by the user.

Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Insurance {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   int currentYear = 2017; //used for calculating the age of the users car
   int maleGender = 1000;
   int femaleGender = 500;

   //Letting user know they are inputting data for car insurance purposes
   System.out.println("Car insurance questionnaire. Please input correct information when prompted.");

   // gender information from user
   System.out.println("What is your gender? m/f");
   String gender = scanner.next();

   // accident quantity information from user
   System.out.println("How many accidents have you had?");
   int acc = scanner.nextInt();

   // car year information from user
   System.out.println("What year was your car manufactured?");
   int carAge = scanner.nextInt();

   //if statements which refer to the users data input
    if (gender.equals("m")) {
     System.out.println("You are a male.\nThe base cost is $1000."); 
     } else {
     System.out.println("You are a female.\nThe base cost is $500.");
     }


     if (acc == 0) {
     System.out.println("You have no accidents. Insurance increase is $0.");
     } else if (acc >= 1) {
     System.out.println("You have " + acc + " accidents. Insurance increase is $" + acc * 100 + ".");
     }


     if (carAge >= 2007) {
      System.out.println("Your car is " + (currentYear - carAge) + " years old.\nYour car is still in warranty, no savings added.");
      } else 
      System.out.println("Your car is out of warranty, final cost is halved.");

      //Total cost
     /*
      if (carAge <= 2007) {
      System.out.println("Your total price is $" + ((acc * 100 + femaleGender) / 2) + ".");
      } else 
      System.out.println("Your total price is $" + (acc * 100 + femaleGender) + ".");
        */


 }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for the java compiler to understand what you want if you write down what you mean ("The base cost is $1000") not only in natural language but in code (`int subtotal; subtotal = 1000;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure how you want to calculate your result but if do NOT want to use `femaleGender` all the time but in dependency of the gender different values then maybe something like this could help:

```
int baseAmount = gender.equals("m") ? maleGender : femaleGender;
if (carAge <= 2007) {
    System.out.println("Your total price is $" + ((acc * 100 + baseAmount ) / 2) + ".");
} else 
    System.out.println("Your total price is $" + (acc * 100 + baseAmount ) + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int genderCost;

...

if (gender.equals("m")) {
    System.out.println("You are a male.\nThe base cost is $1000.");
    genderCost = maleGender;
} else {
    System.out.println("You are a female.\nThe base cost is $500.");
    genderCost = femaleGender;
}

...

if (carAge <= 2007) {
    System.out.println("Your total price is $" + ((acc * 100 + genderCost) / 2) + ".");
} else 
    System.out.println("Your total price is $" + (acc * 100 + genderCost) + ".");
}
```

Put the amount for gender in a variable `genderCost` when the gender input variable is evaluated and use `genderCost` when you calculate the total.

Comment: This also worked, thank you very much, I appreciate your time! :)